# Javascript change date format from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to MM-DD-YYYY

Tags: javascript

I want to change `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` to `MM-DD-YYYY`

Example:
I have a string which represents a date in this format: `2013-06-15 03:00:00`

I want to change this string into `06-15-2013` using JavaScript.

Is there any library to do this? or should i just use JavaScript?

Comment: A *library*? A simple regular expression should be sufficient.

Comment: why you want to do it by javascript? you can do it just by SampleDateFormat

Comment: @Souad: Is there any reason why you encourage to use a Java facility in a JavaScript specific question?

Comment: is this question what you really meant?  because your title is misleading....Javascript change date format from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to MM-DD-YYYY

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function change(time) {
    var r = time.match(/^\s*([0-9]+)\s*-\s*([0-9]+)\s*-\s*([0-9]+)(.*)$/);
    return r[2]+"-"+r[3]+"-"+r[1]+r[4];
}
change("2013-06-15 03:00:00");
```

Comment: needs to not return HH:MM:SS to be correct now.

Answer (score 0):

see moment.js.. i found it very useful
http://momentjs.com/

Comment: Please include at least an example how to use the given library.

Answer (score 0):

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/f6k3H/1/

Javascript:

```
var d = new Date();
var c = new Date('2013-06-15 03:00:00');

alert(formatDate(c));
alert(formatDate(d));

function formatDate(d)
{
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var day = d.getDate();
    month = month + 1;

    month = month + "";

    if (month.length == 1)
    {
        month = "0" + month;
    }

    day = day + "";

    if (day.length == 1)
    {
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    return month + '-' + day + '-' + d.getFullYear();
}
```

Since this doesn't use RegEx you'll notice some weirdness....Examples:

```
d.getMonth() + 1
```

this is because getMonth is 0 indexed....

```
 day = day + "";

    if (day.length == 1)
    {
        day = "0" + day;
    }
```

this is because hours, seconds, minutes all return 1 digit when they are 1 digit...this makes them return a leading 0.  The same can be done to Month and Day if desired.

Comment: Whelp. That's an off-topic answer, the question was how to modify an existing time string, not how to create a new one with the given format.

Comment: valid point...when reading it I changed some words apparently, because i didn't think anyone would want to do what he is asking...mainly because of the question title "Javascript change date format from YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS to MM-DD-YYYY", i've offered an edit to his question, depending on his response I will likely delete this answer.