# Format a date in jquery which is in the format "dd.mm.yy"

Tags: javascript, date

I have string like "02.09.13"'

I want to format this sting to date. For this i have written code like,

```
var date = new Date("02.09.13");
alert(date);
```

It is printing 'NaN'

but this code is working if the string like "02/09/12"

Comment: Try This:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572199/change-date-format-who-is-stored-in-text-field/18572757#18572757

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For All browsers apart from IE (not sure which versions) your code will work

```
var date = new Date('02.09.13');
alert(date);
```

for IE we use :

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse('02.09.13'.replace(/\./ig, '/')));
alert(date);
```

If you actually want to parse a date using the format 'dd.mm.yy' It's worth noting the Date object does not do that out of the box. There is a really good Library called [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) which makes parsing these kind of dates super simple, example below for your date:

```
moment("02.09.13", "DD.MM.YY");
```

Answer (score 0):

NaN show only on iE browser where you need correct date time format.

```
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07); // yyyy, mm-1, dd  
var d = new Date(2011, 01, 07, 11, 05, 00); // yyyy, mm-1, dd, hh, mm, ss  
var d = new Date("02/07/2011"); // "mm/dd/yyyy"  
var d = new Date("02/07/2011 11:05:00"); // "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"  
var d = new Date(1297076700000); // milliseconds  
var d = new Date("Mon Feb 07 2011 11:05:00 GMT"); // ""Day Mon dd yyyy hh:mm:ss GMT/UTC
```

Check this blog: [JavaScript new Date() Returning NaN in IE or Invalid Date in Safari](http://biostall.com/javascript-new-date-returning-nan-in-ie-or-invalid-date-in-safari)

Best Regards

Comment: This is printing NaN/NaN/NaN

Answer (score 0):

**havent tried** `new Date("02.09.13".replace(/\./g, '/'));` // but thinks  13 ~ 1913

**For Date {Sat Feb 09 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Daylight Time)}**

havent tried `new Date("02.09.2013".replace(/\./g, '/'));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the . with /
Like the one given below

```
var unformattedDate= "02.09.13"
var actDate = unformattedDate.replace(/\./g, '/');

var date = new Date( actDate );
alert(date);
```

Hope this may help.