# How to change Date format in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I want to change a date's format in JavaScript. I tried

```
 var today = new Date();
 today.toLocaleFormat('%d-%b-%Y');
```

but that didn't work. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to format javascript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-javascript-date)

Comment: Why not working , its correct only mate. It should work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032735/javascript-change-date-format-from-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-to-mm-dd-yyyy

You can find the solution here ;)
it worked for me.

Comment: toLocaleFormat method of Date object is deprecated...This what link suggests "This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is no straight way to do so. Let's check these out:

```
var date = new Date();
var options = {
    weekday: "long", year: "numeric", month: "short",
    day: "numeric", hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"
};

//alert(date.toLocaleDateString("en-US"));
alert(date.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", options));
```

**And I think you are looking for this:**

```
var myDate = new Date();
alert(myDate.getDate()  + "-" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1)+ "-" + myDate.getFullYear());
```

Yes, I've googled and got this solution. Please [check it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) out. :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please find below my answer ,

```
var today = new Date(); 
var dd = today.getDate(); 
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0! 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear(); 
if(dd<10)
{
    dd='0'+dd
} 
if(mm<10)
{  
    mm='0'+mm 
} 
var today = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat, it is not recommended to use the above function.

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
date = new Date();
date.format('dd st-MMM-yyyy');
```

Here's an [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/773356/Date-and-Time-formatting-in-JavaScript-like-Net-Cs) that explains it in depth.

Comment: format is not a pre-defined method on Date object in javascript.